# "Latters" or "the latter" or "latter" when referring to plural?

Tags: grammar, articles, phrase-usage, nouns, plural-forms

Which of the following are correct ways to refer to the last noun in plural and why:

> As these pieces of code mutate their objects, **the latter** are not safe to pass around.

Or

> As these pieces of code mutate their objects, **the latters** are not safe to pass around.

Or

> As these pieces of code mutate their objects, **latters** are not safe to pass around.

The "latter(s)" is meant to refer to the objects in the plural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Latter is a choosing word. If one has to choose between only two objects, as in the case with the word "Latter", the choice is always singular.

According to [Wordreference Forum](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/the-latter-the-latters.300456/):

> There were babies and dogs being attacked by bees and drama mamas. The
>   victors were, unfortunately, the latter.
>
> Here "the latter" represents the idea of the group. So to answer your
>   question, no, it's never "latters."

Comment: So "latters" is always wrong?

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev Yes

Comment: Thanks. And any way to refer to "mamas" only in your example? The latter from the latter? :)

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev unfortunately, latter can only be used for two things, in this case, those two things being two groups

Comment: So how would I refer to mamas without repeating the word?

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev You could say, "*There were babies and dogs being attacked by bees and drama mamas. The victors were, unfortunately, the latter. Among the victors, the latter were more vicious.*"

Comment: I would have said it's completely ambiguous whether "the latter" here refers to "drama mamas" or to "bees and drama mamas". But that's not relevant to the question...

Comment: @BellaSwan: the latter is a kind of pronoun, more than an adjective, so it is not illogical to think it can take the plural, like 'other' when it is a pronoun and no longer just an adjective: 'the other students', but 'the others'. In 'while Alonso and Gonzalo are asleep, Antonio encourages Sebastian to imitate him, and get rid of his brother to become King of Naples in his stead. They would have killed him and his faithful councillor Gonzalo if the latter had not been woken up by the sounds made by Ariel obeying Prospero,' the latter might refer to Gonzalo alone, or to Gonzalo and Alonso.